# Расстояния в заголовке внутри колонки таблицы

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть файлы

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.hstyle {
    text-align: center;
}

.calltable tr td {
    border-spacing: 40px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.calltable {
    margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Журнал вызовов</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="calllog.css"></link>   
</head>
    <h1 class="hstyle">Журнал вызовов</h1>
    <table class="calltable">
        <tr>
            <td>
                №
            </td>
            <td>
                Дата/Время
            </td>
            <td>
                Входящий абонент
            </td>
            <td>
                Номер телефона
            </td>
            <td>
                Продолжительность
            </td>
            <td>
                Оператор абонента
            </td>
            <td>
                Стоимость вызова
            </td>   
        </tr>
    </table>
</html>
```

1. Почему `border-spacing` не срабатывает в шапке таблицы?
2. Как выровнять содержимое ячеек шапки таблицы (1-я tr)?

Answer (score 1):

Потому что это свойство таблицы, а не ячейки. Правда, не очень понятно, зачем Вам такие расстояния между ячейками - возможно, перед Вами какая-то другая задача стоит, а Вы не тем путём её решаете:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.hstyle {
    text-align: center;
}

.calltable tr td {
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.calltable {
    margin: 15px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-spacing: 40px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="hstyle">Журнал вызовов</h1>
<table class="calltable">
    <tr>
        <td>
            №
        </td>
        <td>
            Дата/Время
        </td>
        <td>
            Входящий абонент
        </td>
        <td>
            Номер телефона
        </td>
        <td>
            Продолжительность
        </td>
        <td>
            Оператор абонента
        </td>
        <td>
            Стоимость вызова
        </td>   
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: я обновил вопрос.

Comment: @webprogerproger, по первому пункту ничего не изменилось - я дал ответ (Вы не тому элементу задаёте border-spacing, потому у Вас он и не работает). По второму пункту не очень понятно: как именно "выровнять" содержимое ячеек? Относительно чего выровнять? Какой результат нужен? Хоть картинку прикрепите, что ли.

Comment: содержимое шапки должно быть отцентрировано.